# Create a grid over a multipolygon layer where grid cells align with polygon border in python

Tags: python, geospatial, spatial, geopandas, shapely

I have a multipolygon layer of long and narrow polygons that cover river banks. I need to create a grid of cells over that polygon, but I need the cells to align with the inner border of the polygon, where in touches the water. the difficult part is that for each feature of the multipolygon goes in a different direction so I need to create a different grid for each part.

so far I was only able to create a simple grid of 20x20, but it does not align in every area.

```
import geopandas as gpd
from shapely import geometry

def create_grid(aoi, size):
   # Get the extent of the shapefile
   total_bounds = aoi.total_bounds
   # Get minX, minY, maxX, maxY
   minX, minY, maxX, maxY = total_bounds

   # Create a fishnet
   x, y = (minX, minY)
   geom_array = []

   # Polygon Size
   square_size = size
   while y <= maxY:
       while x <= maxX:
           geom = geometry.Polygon(
               [(x, y), (x, y + square_size), (x + square_size, y + square_size), (x + square_size, y), (x, y)])
           geom_array.append(geom)
           x += square_size
       x = minX
       y += square_size

   fishnet = gpd.GeoDataFrame(geom_array, columns=['geometry']).set_crs(aoi.crs)
   return fishnet


def clip_grid(aoi, grid):
   # Clip the input shapefile to the AOI
   clipped_gdf = gpd.clip(aoi, grid)
   return clipped_gdf


aoi = gpd.read_file("path_to_aoi.shp")
grid_size = 0.00020

#create grid
grid = create_grid(aoi, grid_size)
# clip grid to aoi
clipped_grid = clip_grid(grid, aoi)
```

Comment: Please show us the sample of plots that meet your requirements.